# É possível ter autenticação pelo IdentityServer4 e Authorização na API, separadamente?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identity-server

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês, porém eu posso ter me expressado mal e não obtive a resposta que eu queria. [Link em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302420/how-to-add-additional-claims-in-api-project-when-using-identityserver-4).

Eu tenho 3 aplicações diferentes: *IdentityServer* que é meu provedor de identidade; *Ensino.MVC* que é o frontend em Asp.net mvc; e *Ensino.Api*. Esta ultima é a Api em si. O processo de autenticação, definição de claims, escopos e tudo mais está pronto e funcionando. Acontece que: na Api eu preciso definir Claims específicas da Api. Por exemplo:

**IdentityServer**: Autentica o usuário e disponibiza o access_token para garantir o acesso de Mvc para Api. Este token contem as claims de Perfil, Email, Id do Usuário e tudo o que se refere ao usuário. Esta aplicação tem acesso somente ao banco de dados de Identidades.

**Ensino.Mvc**: Faz login pelo IdentityServer e guarda o access_token para acesso à Api. Todo este processo é descrito na documentação do IdentityServer4.

**Ensino.Api**: Aqui está a chave da questão. O Token que a api recebe contém as claims referentes ao usuário: Id, perfil, email... Mas a Api precisa restringir o acesso de determinados usuários à determinados recursos. A Api tem acesso somente ao banco de dados da aplicação, e não tem acesso ao banco de dados de identidade. Então na Api, através do Id do usuário, eu busco se ele tem escolas cadastradas. Se tiver, eu devo atribuir a ele a Claim "Diretor". Este mesmo usuário também pode ser aluno, então busco no banco de dados se ele tem "matriculas". Se tiver, eu lhe atribuo a Claim "Estudante". Porém eu não tenho nenhuma ideia de como eu faço isso no nível da Api.

**Resumo:** De acordo com as claims recebidas na Api pelo access-token, tenho que gerar novas claims, que são especificamente da Api, e salvá-las para que possam ser acessadas pelo contexto e validar as Policies. Isso tudo na Api.

Se alguém souber uma forma melhor de fazer este controle de acesso, sugestões são sempre bem vindas.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que o servidor de identidade deva ter somente o necessário do usuário, quaisquer outras informações que seja apenas da aplicação você deve adicionar nas Claims assim que o token é validado.

Para tal você pode usar a instância de `JwtBearerEvents`.

Por que desta forma? Por que você pode aplicar o teu servidor de identidade para várias outras aplicações que nem sempre terão os mesmos dados de usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando para as responsabilidades e para a proposta em si do IdentityServer4, assim como o entendimento que tive, a aplicação Ensino.Api (age como *Resource Provider*) é responsável por disponibilizar um recurso que a aplicação Ensino.Mvc (age como *Client*) deseja acessar.

Partindo então desse entendimento, não é responsabilidade da Ensino.Api gerar Claims de acesso para o usuário, mas sim validar o token e então retornar o recurso solicitado pela aplicação Ensino.Mvc.

Uma solução seria: ao realizar o login em Ensino.Mvc usando o IdentityServer4, no próprio IdentityServer4 antes de você gerar o JWT, verificar (criando uma implementação de [IProfileService](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) por exemplo) a lista de Claims (objeto User.Claims) e realizar sua lógica desejada com os valores *(buscar se ele tem escolas cadastradas, se tiver, eu devo atribuir a ele a Claim "Diretor", buscar no banco de dados se o usuário tem "matriculas" e se tiver, eu lhe atribuo a Claim "Estudante", etc...)*.

Ou seja, no seu autenticador IdentityServer4 você já vai gerar o JWT com as Claims desejadas invés de ficar adicionando Claims em outras aplicações.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Renan. Apesar de ser um problema antigo que tive, é sempre bom ver outras perspectivas. Como o Marcelo Dias disse, e como penso também, o servidor de identidade deve ter a responsabilidade de apenas identificar o usuário e dizer quem é. Cabendo assim a API dar acesso a esse usuário ao que ele tem direito. Por conta do MVC ser apenas uma camada de visão, assim como um app mobile, que também pode ter acesso a API, não cabe a ele o processo de permissões, já que eu deveria replicar a lógica de permissões para outras possíveis interfaces de usuário. Com a API eu centralizo.

Comment: Eu sugeri controlar essa lógica em uma aplicação específica com IdentityServer4 porque em um cenário onde você tiver 10 API's invés de você ter que implementar em cada uma delas as regras de acesso, você implementaria apenas na aplicação com IdentityServer4. Então a aplicação MVC vai na aplicação IdentityServer4, essa aplicação IdentityServer4 configura as Claims e repassa o token para aplicação MVC que por sua vez consegue então acessar a API. Mas é uma opção/sugestão entre outras que resolve o problema :-)